# apache2 virtual host for symfony multiple applications

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I developed a symfony project with multiple applications and I'm trying to configure an adequate apache2 virtual host according the project structure, according the following requirements:

- The server name for all application should be the same
- Each application, should be accessed according the following way: http://www.project.com/app1, http://www.project.com/app2

By the way, how can I share a template for holding a common menu between all the applications?

Some help will appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to accesso from the same domain (server name), virtual hosting is not what you're looking for...